# I see undefined output sequences reading a memory in simulation

Tags: memory, verilog, simulate, test-bench, icarus

I have a question related to the implementation of a clocked SRAM memory which is is supposed to store data written by user and then display the memory content. In addition, I created a module named `display` which eases the reading process so that there is no need to provide the memory address from which data should be extracted, by incrementing a register after each reading. Nevertheless, when I simulate the circuit, I cannot see the correct output; thus, when I read the memory, I notice some undefined output sequences. I posted the corresponding code below.

```
//stores output data
module sram_1port_data(
    input clk,//clocked memory
    input wr_en,//when high, data is written, otherwise is read
    input [15:0] address_in,//suppose timer cannout count more than 13ms
    input [3:0] wr_data,//memory does not sotre values greater than 13(ms)
    output reg [3:0] rd_data
);

reg [3:0] memory [2 ** 15 - 1 : 0];

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(wr_en) memory[address_in] <= wr_data;
    else rd_data <= memory[address_in];
end

endmodule

//display interfacedesigned for the second memory
module display(
    input clk,
    input wr_en,
    input [15:0] address_in,
    input [3:0] wr_data,
    output [3:0] rd_data
);

reg [15:0] pointer,address;

initial pointer = 16'd0;

sram_1port_data i0(.clk(clk),.wr_en(wr_en),.address_in(address),.wr_data(wr_data),.rd_data(rd_data));

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(!wr_en) begin
        address <= pointer;
        pointer <= pointer + 1;
    end 
    else address <= address_in;
end

endmodule

//tb for display
module display_tb(
    output reg clk,
    output reg wr_en,
    output reg [15:0] address_in,
    output reg [3:0] wr_data,
    output [3:0] rd_data
);

display i0(.clk(clk),.wr_en(wr_en),.address_in(address_in),.wr_data(wr_data),.rd_data(rd_data));

initial $dumpvars(0,display_tb);

initial begin
    clk = 1'd1;
    repeat (2000)
    #100 clk = ~clk;
end

initial begin
    wr_en = 1'd1;
    #100000 wr_en = 1'd0;
end

integer i;

initial begin
    wr_data = 3'd0;
    for(i = 1;i < 500;i = i + 1) begin
    #200 wr_data = i;
    end
end

initial begin
    address_in = 16'd0;
    for(i = 1;i < 500;i = i + 1) begin
    #200 address_in = i;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at waveforms, I see that `rd_data` is unknown (X) on every other read.  Looking at an internal address signal, I see that the unknowns are only for even addresses.  Early in the simulation, you are only writing to even addresses.

In your testbench, you are using the same variable (`i`) in 2 different `for` loops.  In your 2nd `for` loop, use a different variable name (`j`, for example):

```
integer j;
initial begin
    address_in = 16'd0;
    for(j = 1;j < 500;j = j + 1) begin
    #200 address_in = j;
    end
end
```

Now, all reads have known values because it writes to all addresses (even and odd).

---

You could also set the address inside the same `for` loop as the write data.  This is likely a better approach in this case.

```
initial begin
    wr_data    =  3'd0;
    address_in = 16'd0;
    for(i = 1;i < 500;i = i + 1) begin
        #200;
        wr_data    = i;
        address_in = i;
    end
end
```